# Node js updating a value returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a value using express and node js API calls. This is what my route looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.put('/updateValue/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  value.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
    new: true
  }, function(err, post) {
    if (err) {
      res.json('value with the entered ID does not exist');
      console.log(err);
    } else {
    res.json(post);
  }
  });
});
```

And this is what my value schema looks like:

```
var value = new mongoose.Schema({
    milliseconds: {
        type: Number
    }
});
```

I can add a value which works great.

**What works:**

- Updating the value with the correct id
- Updating the value with a shorter ID returns an error (as expected)
- Updating the value with a longer ID returns an error (as expected)

**What does not work:**

- When I try to update the value using the same length ID, however changing a figure or two - then I get null returned in the '`post`'

Should it not also return an error? Since the value does not get updated due to an incorrect ID?

Any explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi deeveeABC, have you checked your collection to see if a new value was inserted into it?

Comment: Hey. The value inserts fine when I first add it. However when I try to modify it with the incorrect ID, it does not update in the dbs. If the ID is correct, the value is updated correctly in the dbs

Answer (score 0):

```
if (err) {
      res.json('value with the entered ID does not exist');
      console.log(err);
    }
```

Above code will be run only when mongoose throw error like in your case

- Updating the value with a shorter ID returns an error (as expected)
- Updating the value with a longer ID returns an error (as expected)

**In console you are getting message like: Cast to ObjectId failed for value**

But when you send request with correct format of objectId but with value which is not present in your database ***update*** query will return null.

As while updating you first find the document and then update on it, but  it is not an error,if document is not present.

You can do your code like this:

```
 router.put('/updateValue/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  value.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
    new: true
  }, function(err, post) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err);
      console.log(err);
    } else {
         if(post){
           res.json(post);
           }else{
               res.json('value with the entered ID does not exist');
                }
         }
  });
});
```

In my suggestion everything we take in the request must be validate before going to your database call.Because, getting an error from mongoose is not a good way to write api.

So,in your case you can validate req.params.id is an ObjectId or not

Example for validating:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    function validate(req.params.id){
    var data=req.params.id;
   return  mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(data) ? null : 'Should be an object id.';
    }
```

This is just an example of function you can modify and use it in accordance to your code.

Comment: Thats a great explanation, however I am slightly confused at the end. Where would I put the validate function in my router.put?

Comment: You can put it before **value.findByIdAndUpdate**  if got error send your response message .

Comment: Would you mind editing your code so that both of these are integrated? I am new to Node, and I understand it uses callbacks to control the flow, so just wondering how this would look like integrated together. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

According to [mongoose doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/command/findAndModify/#value), if you use the new: true modifier you will get a null result if mongo does not find your document.

It's not a bug it's a feature.